# Excel: Clear Contents In Cell Of Column A If Cell In Column B Or C Is Empty

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I want to create macros or formula in excel office 2010.

If cell in column B or column C is empty, then clear contents in column A. If cell in column B or column C is not empty, then don't clear contents in A.

I have a table with range from A1 to C10 and I want to check value at cell  B1:B10 and C1:C10.

I find that formula: `=IF(ISBLANK(B1);"";"YOUR VALUE HERE")`

But when I try to use it I have this problem: when is false, content in A1 is change of 0.

Comment: Pls refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting Query

Comment: Try using the `Macro Recorder` on how to clear cells, and then look at Workbook events.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code the first time to correct all data (it's erase data in col A that you won't recover),
 you just have to change `SheetName` to the name of your sheet :

```
Sub testMR()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wS As Worksheet

    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
    LastRow = LastRow_1(wS)

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        With wS
            If .Cells(i, 2) <> vbNullString Or .Cells(i, 3) <> vbNullString Then
            Else
                'B and C empty
                .Cells(i, 1) = vbNullString
            End If
        End With 'wS
    Next i
End Sub


Public Function LastRow_1(wS As Worksheet) As Double
    With wS
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            LastRow_1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            LastRow_1 = 1
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Place this in the sheet's module in which you desire to automate the behavior :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Me
        If .Cells(Target.Row, 2) <> vbNullString _
           Or .Cells(Target.Row, 3) <> vbNullString Then
        Else
            'B and C empty
            .Cells(Target.Row, 1) = vbNullString
        End If
    End With 'Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :))))

Comment: @M.R. : You are welcome! Just take a minute to take the tour and learn how the SO community works (accepting answers and upvoting) : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thank you, I will do it! :)

Comment: Hey, @R3uK! I want to use your code, but not from row 1. My table start from row 13 to row 22. Would you help me, please? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @M.R. : Just change `Me.Range("B:C")` to `Me.Range("B13:C22")`! ;)

Comment: I tried but that clear contents from row 1 to row 12.

Comment: @M.R. : Do you use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`? And did you only changed the line `If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`?

Comment: I changed only Me.Range("B:C") to Me.Range("B13:C22")

Comment: After the line `With Me`, insert `MsgBox Target.Row & "_" & .Cells(Target.Row,2).Row` try to change a value and see if those 2 numbers are the same as the line you changed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135938/discussion-between-m-r-and-r3uk).